# How to connect with Python Sockets to another computer on the same network

Tags: python, sockets

So I was trying to figure out a way to use sockets to make a terminal-based chat application, and I managed to do it quite well. Because I could only test it on one computer, I didn't realize that it might not work on different computers. My code is as simple as this:

```py
# Server
import socket
HOST = "0.0.0.0"
PORT = 5555

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print("Connected to", addr)
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print("Received:", data.decode())
            conn.sendall(data)
```

```py
# Client
import socket
HOST = "192.168.0.14"
PORT = 5555

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b"Hello this is a connection")
    data = s.recv(1024)
print("Received:", data.decode())
```

I've tried changing the ip to 0.0.0.0, use gethostname a lot of other things, but it just doesn't work. The server is up and running, but the client can't connect. Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the servers IP on the network? Is it `192.168.0.14`?

Comment: Your program works if you use localhost for the address in the server and the client.  I think that you have a firewall/permissions issue.  See my answer below.

Comment: The problem is that localhost works on one computer, but I want to connect between two computers. How would I do that?

Comment: @rdas Yes, I think so. When I use ipconfig, that's what it says.

Comment: @Ray Do you get any errors?

Comment: Yes, just the connection refused.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that 0.0.0.0 means connect from anywhere which means that you have to allow port 5555 through your firewall.

[image]

Instead of 0.0.0.0 use localhost as the address in both the client and the server.

I just tested your code using `localhost` for the server and the client and your program worked.

server:

```
Connected to ('127.0.0.1', 53850)
Received: Hello this is a connection
```

client:

```
Received: Hello this is a connection
```

As you can see, all that I changed was the address on both the server and the client.  If this doesn't work then there is something outside of your program that is preventing you from success.  It could be a permissions issue or another program is listening on port 5555.

**server.py**

```
# Server
import socket
HOST = "0.0.0.0"
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 5555

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print("Connected to", addr)
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print("Received:", data.decode())
            conn.sendall(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

**client.py**

```
# Client
import socket
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 5555

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b"Hello this is a connection")
    data = s.recv(1024)
print("Received:", data.decode())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Comment: I don't get the firewall dialog though, so what should I do?

Comment: Did you use loacalhost for the address?

Comment: @Ray, are you using windows or linux?

Comment: @Ray I just tried your code using 2 different systems. The server being windows and the client being linux. The  program just works fine.There could be multiple ethernet adaptors/wireless adaptors. Are you sure you are using the right IP?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I'll give it a go again

Comment: When I press Ctrl+C, it says that it broke out while the client was trying to connect.

Comment: @Ray, try a different port number.  There might be another service using that port.

Comment: What operating system are you running on?  and what user are you? root? administrator?

Comment: Just a normal user

Comment: Just wondering, is it possible to connect from a VirtualBox to the host machine using sockets? How would I go about doing that? Would it be the same as what I was doing in the question?

Comment: Yes, all you need is the ip of the server app's computer.  If the VM is hosting the server app then you probably need to change the VM's network adapter to a bridged network adapter.